# Apply projective transformation on plane in 3D

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, three.js

**Scenario**
I have a 3D environment which contains a 3D scene and a '2D' scene.
The 3D scene contains a cube and a perspective camera.
The '2D' scene contains 4 round objects and an orthographic camera. These round objects can be moved around by the user therefor the orthographic camera is used otherwise the round objects can be moved 'in depth' (along z-axis) and could change in size and i want them to maintain size.
Depending on positioning the round objects, the corners of the cube in the 3D scene should be aligned with the positions of the round objects. And maintaining perspective.
*Edit:* 
What i am trying to accomplish is: Based on an image of a room a user uses those round objects to define the dimensions of the room. Based on those dimensions a hidden cube is positioned to act as a boundery box. The next step would be to add 3d objects to the scene and maintaining perspective of the room.
I tried explaining this scenario in a picture:
[image: situation sketch]
**Problems**
Basically i have no clue where to start.
The round objects are in a '2D' environment because of the orthographic camera, therefor i have no depth value that i think i need.
I think i need some perspective transformation based on camera positions/settings? There are all sorts of matrices that could be produced but don't know how to implement them.
**Sources i studied**
http://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm/affine-and-projective-transformations.htm
*below is a similar situation*
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript
*Cannot post more links because of my reputation*
I hope someone can make this clear or point me in the right direction

Comment: I'm confused. If the balls are in a 2D scene, how can they move in depth? And how does a change in size correspond to your goal of maintaining size? Is it that you consider these balls to have fixed size in 3D, so that the 2D representations may appear at different sizes due to *z* distance? If so, then size is essentially just another word for *z* position, and your balls would have 3D coordinates even in the orthographic scene. Otherwise I think I'm missing something here. Note: a general 3D-to-2D projection has 11 real degrees of freedom, while knowing 4 2D image points only provides 8.

Comment: They can't. They are in an orthographic scene so that they maintain same size when dragged. And therefor don't have z positions, at least to my knowledge. What i am trying to accomplish is basically the same as what happens in augmented reality that uses markers. In fact, it's exactly the same, but in stead of using the markers i use user draggable points to act as a marker. Those markers are also 2D representations of a 'plane', am i right?

Comment: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YEaVZ.jpg) ;image courtesy of arview. This is exactly what i am trying to do. Instead of the marker i want to use user draggable corner objects (the balls)

Answer (score 0):

Counting the real degrees of freedom, I would say that you don't have enough data. Imagine the projetive camera of the 3D scene as an actual pinhole camera. Then the image that camera creates on its film, sensor or whatever is described by at least 9 parameters:

- 3 parameters for the position of the camera in space,
- 2 parameters for the direction the camera is looking at and
- 1 parameter rotating the camera + sensor around their optical axis,
- 1 parameter determining the distance from pinhole to sensor and
- 2 parameters translating the sensor in its plane

On the other hand, knowing a projective transformation from one plane to another, e.g. using [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) to the question you already referenced, will only yield 8 geometrically meaningful parameters. So you cannot hope to reconstruct the camera position from that, so you cannot find the image of the 3D scene that would fit your markers. The Wikipedia article on [3D pose estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_pose_estimation) writes that

> Most implementations of POSIT only work on non-coplanar points (in other words, it won't work with flat objects or planes).<sup>[[3]](http://web.archive.org/web/20100620131054/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Posit)</sup>

That being said, you gave an example of where someone is actually doing this! So how do they do it? Honestly, I'm not sure, but they would have to make use of some additional knowledge or extra assumptions. For example, if they knew details about their camera (focal length, relative position between lens and sensor, or something like that), that could provide the required data. Since these apps tend to work on mobile devices, I think it rather likely that they might have either an API to request these things or a database where they can be looked up for the more common devices.

Judging from your question, you don't have that. Neither do you have all the vertical edges of the cube depicted vertically parallel to one another, which would have been another possible way to add more information. You have to come up with one more piece of information in order to allow for a hopefully unique solution.

Of course, without more information the system is just underspecified. It's not hard to find *any* transformation matrix which does what you requested. Actually [the answer I references](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) is placed in a setup where a 2D to 2D map is to be modeled using a 3D transformation matrix. You can do the same and be done with it. But your users might become frustrated, since the transformation they obtain might do completely wrong things to the out-of-plane direction, and there is no knob to tune that to the correct behavior.

Comment: You also know, that these four points all lie on the same 3D plane, and form a rectangle (corners are 90°).